# make spring boot project as a subproject

Tags: spring-boot

I have three subprojects in my MainProject, while one of the subporjects works as a common project providing services. How to make this project structure based on spring boot?

```
MainProject
|
|__subprojects
|        |
|        |__projectA    (run as spring boot project)
|        |     |   
|        |     |_pom.xml
|        |
|        |__common      (provide services to A & B)
|        |     |    
|        |     |_pom.xml
|        |
|        |__projectB    (run as spring boot project)
|              |   
|              |_pom.xml
|
|__pom.xml
```

This is the way I did: 
First, I make my common project as a spring boot project.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I use @ComponentScan, @MapperScan to get components and mapers, and this subproject works fine as a SpringBootApplication.

Then, something's wrong when I run projectA. Here's the pom.xml in projectA:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

projectA ran as the same way of common:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.aaa.common.service",
    "com.common.mapper",
    "com.projectA.controller",})
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"com.common.mapper",})
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProejctAConf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProejctAConf, args);
    }
}
```

but program got error with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@60015ef5: startup date [Wed Sep 13 16:15:06 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

Is there a good solution to run projectA as spring boot application ? or I just run projectA in the wrong way? or my project structure is not right?

TIA

Comment: Is `common` actually a spring-boot project or just a common-library? If it's just a library then why are you requiring spring-boot related dependencies into `common`? You should require them into each spring-boot project(project A and B).

Comment: I wanna use common as a library, but also use @MapperScan when common project access data in mysql